# Check inside for loop is not executed

Tags: python, speech, pocketsphinx, espeak

I am working on a project to make the computer speak back when I give it commands. I just started, but when I run the code, it doesn't respond in the way I expect it to respond. Here is my code:

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
import os
for phrase in LiveSpeech(): print(phrase)
if phrase == 'oh' :
    os.system('espeak' ' "hi"')
```

I got an error when I run this code. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxt", line 4, in <module>
    print(phrase)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 93, in __str__
    return self.hypothesis()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 126, in hypothesis
    hyp = self.hyp()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.py", line 359, in hyp
    return _pocketsphinx.Decoder_hyp(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 225, in stop
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
```

Thanks,
      Aditya

Comment: This perhaps is too simple, but are you sure that your `if` statement is being executed in your `for` loop? It looks like your `for` loop simply prints each phrase without checking if the value of the phrase is `'oh'`. Try adding a newline before `print` and indenting that line, as well as the two lines beneath it to be nested under the `for` loop.

Comment: @cole Thanks, but it is not working

Comment: Hello? Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the if statement is not in the loop, the loop's body is the print statement

```
for phrase in LiveSpeech():
    print(phrase)
    if phrase == 'oh' :
        os.system('espeak' ' "hi"')
```

this is what it  should look like

Comment: You have to use tabs.  That's what Python uses for resolving scope

Comment: @MatTheWhale I am not talking about that, the answer above does not work on my computer.

Comment: what error are you getting in my version of the code?

Comment: Hello? Anybody there?

Comment: you will need to dig into it bit more I fixed the loop issue for you. Stop iteration means that you consumed all data, the source told you there is nothing else to read and you read it anyway ( you or the LiveSpeech)

Comment: I didn't get that.